# Storing Data from an Nmap Subprocess into a List Directly

Tags: python, list, subprocess, nmap

I have the following to get a list of IPs from running an nmap subprocess:

```
import subprocess
import os

def get_hosts(ips, exclude_file, outfile):
    # Run the NMAP for given IPs
    output = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', ips, '-sn', '-T4', '-oG', 'temp.txt', '--excludefile', exclude_file], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # Open temp file
    file = open('temp.txt', 'r')
    # Get IP addresses
    ip_list = []
    for line in file:
        a = line.split(" ")
        # Bypass first and last line
        if a[1] == 'Nmap':
            pass
        else:
            ip_list.append(a[1])
    # Close file
    file.close()
    # Remove temp file
    os.remove('temp.txt')
    return ip_list

ips = get_hosts('10.0.0.0/8', 'exclude.txt', 'output.txt')
print (ips)
```

I would like to be able to store these in the list without having to create a temp file and delete it.  Is this possible?  I'm fairly new to python so anything would help.

Comment: You mean to store in a `list` the IPs returned from `nmap` subprocess?

Comment: Correct.  I want it to return in a list without having to first create the temporary file I currently use to pull the data from.

Comment: I believe, this has to do with redirecting the output of `subprocess.Popen`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [nmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) documentation:

> Output
>
> ...
>
> Nmap makes output available in five different formats. **The default is
>   called interactive output,. and it is sent to standard output
>   (stdout)..** There is also normal output,. which is similar to
>   interactive except that it displays less runtime information and
>   warnings since it is expected to be analyzed after the scan completes
>   rather than interactively.
>
> ...
>
> **While interactive output is the default and has no associated command-line options**, the other four format options use the same
>   syntax. They take one argument, which is the filename that results
>   should be stored in.

So I think, instead of saving the output of `nmap` process into `temp.txt` file, just leave it by default sending to `stdout`, this way:

```
>>> output = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', ips, '-sn', '-T4'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then to check for the results, use [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
>>> output.communicate()
```

> Popen.communicate(input=None)
>
> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to
>   terminate. The optional input argument should be a string to be sent
>   to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.
>
> communicate() returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).
>
> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get
>   anything other than None in the result tuple, you need to give
>   stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE too.
>
> Note
>
> The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.

The Output would be something similar to:

```
>>> output.communicate()
('\nStarting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-05 00:58 GST\nNmap scan report for 10.0.2.3\nHost is up (0.011s latency).\nNmap scan report for 10.0.2.15\nHost is up (0.000059s latency).\n', None)
```

Which is a tuple of `(stdout,stderr)`, Then just take the first element of this tuple and retrieve the IPs you want by parsing, through using for example [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=regex#module-re).